# Percentage operation gives different results with two scientific calculator

Tags: calculator, percentages

The operation is: $21.99 + 9.75$$\%$

On the Texas Instruments model TI36X-Pro the answer is: $22.0875$

But when I tried on the Casio FX-991ES Plus the result is: $24.134025$

Which is the correct answer?

And how these two calculators reach different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how we 'read' $21.99 + 9.75\%$

(1)  As $\%$ is derived from the latin 'per centum' (which means 'out of one hundred'), we have
$$ 9.75\% = \frac{9.75}{100} = 0.00975 $$
giving answer one.

(2) Many calculators allow the input `21.99 + 9.75%` being a shortcut for the operation 'add 9.75% of 21.99 to the given 21.99', which is 
$$ 9.75\% \cdot 21.99 = 2.144025 $$
giving the second answer.

If I should choose the 'correct' one, this would be (1), but the better way is not to use notation like that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $9.75\% = 0.0975$, the correct answer is $22.0875$.

The number you got with the second calculator is actually $21.99 \cdot 1.0974$, which is the number $21.99$, *increased by* $9.75$ percent.

With more simple numbers:

If I add $\frac12$, which is $50\% $ to the number $10$, I will get $10+\frac12 = \frac{21}{2}=10.5$. However, if I *increase* $10$ by $50\%$, I will increase it by $5$ (because $5=\frac12 10$) and get $15$.

Answer (score 2):

Other calculators give yet more answers:

- Simply divide argument by 100:
  ${\bf 22.0875} = 21.99 + (9.75 / 100)$
  *e.g. Texas Instruments TI36X-Pro*
- Use argument to add mark up<sup>1</sup>:
  ${\bf 24.134025} = 21.99 \times (1 + 9.75 / 100)$
  *e.g. Casio FX-991ES Plus, [MS Windows Calculator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080110-00/?p=23853/)*
- Use argument to add [margin](http://www.accountingtools.com/questions-and-answers/what-is-the-difference-between-margin-and-markup.html):
  ${\bf 24.36565} = 21.99 \div (1 - 9.75 / 100)$
  *e.g. [Casio DS-20](https://www.boards.ie/b/thread/2056576310)*
- Total as percent of second argument:
  ${\bf 325.53846} = (21.99 + 9.75) \div 9.75 \times 100$
  *e.g. [Casio fx-3400P](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/777145/Casio-Fx-3400p.html?page=28#manual), Casio fx-115W, [Casio fx-260](http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?t=87153)*
- Some calculators have no percentage button.
  *e.g. [Texas Instruments TI84 Plus](http://www.computerforum.com/threads/ti-84-plus-calculator-question.128887/)*

There is no consensus for the calculator keystrokes "<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>", and probably not<sup>2</sup> for the notation "$21.99+9.75\%$", so there isn't a right answer.

And that's just for addition<sup>3</sup>.  So don't rely on the percent button without knowing what that particular model of calculator does!

<sub>1. I have found the mark up behaviour to be the most common for no-frills office calculators.</sub>


<sub>2. What would "$1.23 + 9.8\% + 3.32 + 66.4\%$" mean?</sub>


<sub>3. See also [*Calculators are needlessly bad*](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csharold/cv/files/hucalc.pdf) by Harold Thimbleby (*Int. J. Human-Computer Studies* (2000) 52, 1031-1069).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The Casio one adds $9.75\%$ of $21.99$, which is $2.144025$.

The Texas one adds $9.75\% = 0.0975$ as a plain number.

As to which one is correct, that depends on the specific question.